# Centering table in itemize environment

Tags: latex

I would like to include a centered tabular inside an itemize environment item, is this possible? This is what I am working with, but I can't find a way to center the tabular. Paragraphs are not allowed inside items...

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Text before tabular 
      \newline
      \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
      \end{tabular}
      \newline
      text after tabular
    \item second item
  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the table centered relative to the other list contents or to the whole page?

For the whole page, what is wrong with the obvious solution:

```
\newenvironment{nscenter}
 {\parskip=0pt\par\nopagebreak\centering}
 {\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Text before tabular
    \begin{nscenter}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
      a & b & c \\
      a & b & c \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{nscenter}
    text after tabular
  \item second item
\end{itemize}
```

(with credit to this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98893)).

For centering relative to the other contents, this works:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
      Text before tabular\\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
          a & b & c \\
          a & b & c \\
        \end{tabular}}\\
      Text after tabular\\
      \end{tabular}
\item Second item
\end{itemize}
```

But I admit that it's not very pretty. Maybe someone else has a better solution?

Comment: thanks. Relative to other list contents would be better I guess

Comment: I've added a rough solution for relative to list contents, but I'm not very proud of it.